# "I could aught but surrender"_ "The Pale Blue Eye", Louis Bayard

Tags: meaning

Harrowed hard, I could aught but surrender To the maid with the pale blue eye. To the ghoul with the pale blue eye.

What does "I could aught but surrender"... mean in the preceding passage from Louis Bayard's "The Pale Blue Eye" (opening chapter)? What does "aught" mean?

The chapter starts with a poem in the style of Poe:

From the title poem: "Mid the groves of Circassian splendour / In a brook darkly dappled with sky, / In a moon-shattered brook raked with sky, / Athene's lissome maidens did render / Obeisances lisping and shy: / There I found Leonore, lorn and tender, / In the clutch of a cloud-rended cry. / **Harrowed hard, I could aught but surrender** / To the maid with the pale blue eye / To the ghoul with the pale blue eye."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141882/discussion-on-question-by-anjan-i-could-aught-but-surrender-the-pale-blue-e).

Answer (score 1):

*[DailyWritingTips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/aught-vs-naught/)* explains that *aught* started to be used instead of *naught* at some point:

> ***Aught*** means “something” or “anything”; it’s from the Old English word ***awiht***, meaning “ever a thing.” *Aught* in the sense of “***nothing***” derives from *naught* (from the Old English *nawiht*, meaning “not a thing”). *Now, people sometimes therefore use **aught** when they mean **naught***.

Garner sees this as a mistake, but agrees that it has become standard English:

> *Garner’s Modern American Usage* says that was originally a mistake. >> By error, ***a nought*** (= a zero) was widely misconstrued as ***an aught***. Thus, *aught* has come—mistakenly—to bear the sense ‘zero.’” ([Language Corner](https://archives.cjr.org/language_corner/language_corner_072814.php#:%7E:text=As%20a%20rule%20of%20thumb,is%20preferred%20outside%20of%20math.))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aught) has an interesting usage note:

> > If you know ***aught*** which does behove my knowledge 
> >  Thereof to be inform'd, imprison't not 
> >  In ignorant concealment.
>
> Polixenes begs Camillo in William Shakespeare's *The Winter's Tale*, employing *the "anything" sense of **aught***. Shakespeare didn't coin the pronoun aught, which has been a part of the English language since before the 12th century, but he did put it to frequent use.

Louis Bayard's sentence

> I could ***aught but*** surrender

can be rewritten as

> I could [do] nothing [else] but surrender.

Here is another use of *aught but* quoted by [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/aught-2012-08-08):

> He dropped, dead, into the shallow water, but I was *too late for **aught but** revenge*. (From Judson Roberts' 2011 novel *Viking Warrior*)

which is to be understood as

> too late for ***anything*** [else] *but* revenge.

And here's a quote from the letter from an Irish soldier during WWI:

> Here man may wander uncontrolled by ***aught but*** his desires.([source](https://www.tcd.ie/library/fitasfiddles/title-49/))

Comment: I don't buy that ***Now**, people sometimes therefore use "aught" when they mean "naught"* for this *specific* situation. As @Kate comments under the question, *[do] **nothing** but...* is the substitution that makes most sense here. But my NGram link clearly shows that a couple of centuries ago we almost always wrote *could **aught** but*, not *could **naught** but*, which directly contradicts the assertion made in DailyWritingTips.

Comment: Maybe it's a regional phenomenon: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aught) defines _aught_ as: _**a less common word for nought**_.

Comment: Yes, that's my opinion, too. In *some* cases the ***aught=anything, naught=nothing*** distinction is meaningful, but in others the two terms are equivalent. Bottom line is it doesn't really matter, because there are so few native speakers still actually *using* these words today (in transcribed speech it's normally ***owt / nowt*** nowadays, invariably with the strongly-implied association "uneducated"). See my most recent comment under the Q itself. Mostly what we're now seeing in print is bungled modern attempts to reflect archaic usages.